# Change Default Artwork in iTunes 11

Tags: itunes

How do I change the default artwork for an artist in iTunes 11?

Comment: What do you mean with "default artwork for an artist"? Artwork is defined by album usually (or by track).

Comment: I think Bradley means that iTunes chooses a seemingly random album cover as artist artwork, the question being how to set it manually.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: In iTunes 10, you could set it.

Comment: Yup, you could set it in iTunes 10. I once did it for all my artists, but now I can't seem to do it in iTunes 11.

Answer (score 1):

They seem to have found [a fix, but for Windows](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4558652?start=0&tstart=0). I haven't found a similar one for Mac, I'll update this answer if I find it.

Note: The above only applies to changing the default artwork for viewing by **genre**, not by **artist**, which is still the unanswered question.

While it is possible to change this by [playing with ratings](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4589822?start=0&tstart=0), there doesn't seem to be a manual workaround, as existed in 10.7.